# I can't get the vertical scrollbar to be visible

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello everyone I had a quick question.  I can't get the vertical scrollbar to be visible, it's behaving like overflow: auto;

I've tried
overflow: scroll;

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

none of them worked. Am I missing something simple? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, please edit your question and include the relevant HTML. Second, the vendor-prefixed selectors are not necessary as the CSS you are trying to work with is standard and has been for some time.

Comment: I cannot confirm the issue you describe. `html { overflow-y: scroll }` works fine for me. Please post a [repro] that shows the issue.

Comment: You have a quick question, so I would like to give a quick comment. Try this: `<html>
<div style="height:150px;width:100px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
</div></html>`

Answer (score 0):

The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

You need to set a width and height for the scroll bar to show.

EXAMPLE:

```html
<div>
This is a resizeble div and i am very long... hey? LOL LOL LOL LOL  
</div>

<style>
div {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added that I had a height of 600px, but I got it to work somehow by copy/pasting the code into a new file and then running.  Not sure why that worked but thank you for all your help.